# Render react component in Backbone view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs, backbone.js

I have an existing rails-backbone app I'de like to add React to. For now, I'de like to add a single React component as a widget to an existing Backbone view.

I've used [`react_on_rails`](https://github.com/shakacode/react_on_rails) to add React to Rails, and it's working great when I render the react component using `react_component` in the Rails view (erb file added to Rails routes), but I can't seem to add a component to an existing Backbone view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I asked the same in the repo page, and based on the [gem author response](https://github.com/shakacode/react_on_rails/issues/649) I ended up doing the following:

First, in the backbone view, I add the react container div:

```
@$el.html('<div id="react_widget"></div>')
```

Then, I call react using `ReactOnRails.render`:

```
react_props = {} // I used this to pass models and collection from backbone to react
ReactOnRails.render("OrganizationGroupSettings", react_props, 'react_widget');
```